# How to decompress and compress files in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a script that generates all the zip files. I want to decompress it to .csv files and then again compress it to .gz files. Is it possible with the cozyroc zip task?

Comment: Why do you need SSIS to do this? Why not PowerShell, or a C# utility? What exactly have you tried to do?

Comment: Actually I'm working on an ETL job to ftp the files in gzip fomat in s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any command line utility like 7 zip .

Execute the command using **Execute process task** .

Please go throw below link it is describing step by .

step.https://dataintegrity.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/dynamically-zipping-files-in-ssis/